# Zeros of analytic radial function

Tags: analytic-functions

Suppose $f$ is an analytic radial function. I just read in a paper that the number of zeros of $f$ in the interval $[-R,R]$ will then be bounded above by a multiple of $R$. I'm struggling to see how I would go about proving this. Any tips?

Comment: Is  there any non-constant radial analytic function?

Comment: The function in question (in this case) is the Fourier transform of the indicator function for a ball, say the unit ball, in $\mathbb{R}^n$. This will be an analytic function, and a radial function. And supposedly, these two things alone should enable me to conclude that the number of zeros for this function in $[-R,R]$ is bounded by $CR$, where presumably $C$ does not depend on $R$.

Comment: I don't know what notion of analyticity you are using but there is no analytic function in the sense of complex analysis which is radial, except for constants.

Comment: I don't believe this is meant in the sense of complex analysis, from what I can gather the function should be real analytic.